# (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: the database system is starting up, docker + redis + celery

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, flask, redis

Am trying to run Postgres, Celery, Redis, and the project itself in docker, but it seems the database is not connecting at all. It tries to connect and fails.

Below is the error it throws after running docker :

```
travel_dev_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
travel_dev_container |     connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
travel_dev_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
travel_dev_container |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
travel_dev_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 493, in connect
travel_dev_container |     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
travel_dev_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
travel_dev_container |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
travel_dev_container | psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

Am wondering what I have configured wrong, below is my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  redis:
    container_name: redis_huxy_tour_dev_container
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  db:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    image: postgres:latest
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 5405:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  flask_service:
    container_name: travel_dev_container
    restart: always
    image: flask
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - redis
        - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
        - FLASK_DEBUG=1
        - FLASK_APP=run.py
        - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://test:test@db/test
        - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
        - WEATHER_API_KEY=1d4ce67223a53a013fc03ead36137396
        - SECRET_KEY=jfdjhfl
```

then, my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir app

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

# Install the Python libraries
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

#CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

finally, the shell script file `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#Run migrations
flask db upgrade

# Run Celery worker
celery -A app.tasks.weather_tasks.celery worker -l info &

# Run Celery beat
celery -A app.tasks.weather_tasks.celery beat -l info &

python run.py
```

What could be the reason of this error

Comment: It frequently takes the database 30-60 seconds to start up; the issue is literally what it says in the error message.  If you try starting `docker-compose up -d` again after waiting a bit, does it come up?

Comment: Let me try that, since I was using `docker-compose up --build` @DavidMaze

Comment: So running `docker-compose up -d` has completed , can I run this again `docker-compose up --build ` ?

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks this is close `docker-compose up -d`, it runs in the background

Answer (score 4):

You can use [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) dependencies on your containers.

On your `flask_application` container, under dependencies, use:

```
depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Now you must implement a way to determine when postgres is healthy.
To do that, you can run a healthcheck test command on your `db` container:

```
db:
      healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q"]
```

In case you are getting some error like `FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`, make use of this healthcheck command instead, and ensure your **environment variables** are set accordingly:

```
db:
    healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
```

Your `flask_application` container will now not start until postgres is ready

Comment: A decent approach, although it does slow things down a bit, since the web container can't begin until the database is fully ready.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a wrapper to test for the database to be ready before running the flask app. [Docker Docs titled "Control startup and shutdown order in Compose"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) has an example script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e
  
host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"
  
until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
  
>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

Make this script executable `chmod +x wait-for-postgres.sh`
and change the flask startup command to be:

`command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "python", "app.py"]`

In your case, you would add the `command` in the `flask_service` section of the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  flask_service:
  ...
    command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I don't know why am getting this : 
```entrypoint.sh: line 11: command:: command not found```

Comment: Hey Foo, am having issues regarding where to place `command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "python", "app.py"]`, do I need to place it inside my `entrypoint.sh`, or directly;y in the service, because you mentioned about changing the flask startup ?

Comment: I put my `command` line in the `docker-compose.yml` for the flask container. updated my answer

Comment: Since you have 2 data stores, you'll probably want to tailor the shell script to test for both datastores to boot up before starting the app

Comment: OK, but isn't a repetition on `entrypoint.sh`, since it's already called in `Dockerfile`, because am getting this error now after following your updated answer. 

-----
ERROR: for flask_service  Cannot start service flask_service: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./wait-for-postgres.sh\": permission denied": unknown

Comment: you need to `chmod +x wait-for-postgres.sh` before building the image. this command will be run instead of the `CMD` in `Dockerfile` with this script. i put it in my `docker-compose.yml` because that's where the script needs to run & not when I'm starting the flask Docker on its own

Comment: I did it and no longer get the error, but the database is still saying the same issue , this is the l[ogs](https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/00b9434b5074eb337302a527952c0e2b)

Comment: what does `docker logs travel_dev_container` say? seems like the flask container isn't waiting for the postgres to start